# Solr boosting result by field value

Tags: php, apache, sorting, solr

I am querying a solr server for locations. Those location documents also have a field "country_code" which contains values like US, GB, DE, ...

Under certain circumstances I want to boost results with specific country codes so that I am able to prioritize my results by country.

For example:

```
?q=york
```

Let's say the user is from Great Britain and is searching for York ... At the moment he finds some Yorks in the US first, then the one in England.

I want to be able to specify that for this query British results should be on top. I found that this should be possible via dismax and bq, something like that:

```
?q=york&dismax=true&bq=country_code:GB^20.0
```

But that doesn't work as expected, now York from Guatemala (country_code GT) is on top, the GB ones are not to be seen.

Help please ;-)

Comment: Can you include relevancy results from your query?

Comment: Do you mean the score of the results? without dismax the US results have a score of 1.7357568, the GB has 1.7085013. With dismax York in Guatemala has 2.067986 and the second result in Canada has 2.067986

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, what I did with dismax in my question is working, I just had the boost value way too low. Changed it from 20 to 20000 and it's working just fine.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me after ages scratching my head! In the documentation I can only see really low values being used.

Answer (score 7):

The bq param of dismax is additive, meaning it adds to the final score. There is a boost param in the new edismax parser, which multiplies the boost function value to the final score, [edismax boost](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#bq_.28Boost_Query.29).